# Why is this 2D array comparison not working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So, I got:

```
array1 = 
[
 ["Fisrt Name1", "Last Name1", "email@email.com"],
 ["Fisrt Name2", "Last Name2", "email2@email.com"],
 ["Fisrt Name3", "Last Name2", "email3@email.com"]
]
```

```
array2 = 
[
 ["email2@email.com"],
 ["email3@email.com"],
]
```

I'm trying to compare them and keep uniques from `array1` in the following ways and it should return:

```
resultingArray = 
[
 ["Fisrt Name1", "Last Name1", "email@email.com"],
 ["Fisrt Name3", "Last Name2", "email3@email.com"]
]
```

...but it's returning everything.

Attemp1:

```
resultingArray = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e));
```

Attemp2:

```
let resultingArray = [];
for (let a = 0; a < array1.length; a++){
    for (let n= 0; n < array2.length; n++){
      if(array1[a][2].indexOf(array2[n][0]) === -1){
        resultingArray.push(array1[a])
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final edited answer after refactoring the code.

```js
array1 = [
    ['Fisrt Name1', 'Last Name1', 'email@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name2', 'Last Name2', 'email2@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name3', 'Last Name3', 'email3@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name4', 'Last Name4', 'email4@email.com'],
];

array2 = [['email2@email.com'], ['email3@email.com']];

let resultingArray = [];
first: for (let a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
    second: for (let n = 0; n < array2.length; n++) {
        if (array1[a][2] === array2[n][0]) {
            continue first;
        }
    }
    resultingArray.push(array1[a]);
}

console.log(resultingArray);
```

Here I've used labels. More about [labels.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Tried it, but it's returning eveything - curiously!

Comment: Are you sure? because it's working fine for me with given data array1 & array2.

Comment: Sorry, but what if ```array2``` has more than one element? I've added ```email3@email.com``` and only the first row of data should be in ```resultingArray```, but I get all of them. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I've edited my answer again. Hope it works great this time!

Comment: hi @SelinJodhani you can use snippets for your answer so that code can be run and tested here itself

Comment: hey @cmgchess. This was my first answer on StackOverflow. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare 2 reference values ( array or object)
Maybe something like

```js
array1 = [
    ['Fisrt Name1', 'Last Name1', 'email@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name2', 'Last Name2', 'email2@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name3', 'Last Name3', 'email3@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name4', 'Last Name4', 'email4@email.com'],
];

array2 = [['email2@email.com'], ['email3@email.com']];

const result = array2.map(item => array1.filter(e => !e.includes(item[0])))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi! This returns ```array1 = [
    ['Fisrt Name1', 'Last Name1', 'email@email.com'],
    ['Fisrt Name2', 'Last Name2'],
    ['Fisrt Name3', 'Last Name2', 'email3@email.com'],
];``` , excluding only the email, but keeping ```First Name2``` and ```Last Name2```. What would be the tweak to get only unfound contacts? Thanks.

Comment: I will test it and refactor it and update the comment !

Comment: Sorry...I did try it, but it doesn't work. I've added one more element to ```array2```, so ```resultingArray``` should contain only one line, but it's returning all of them. Appreciate your help